# Editing a live journey in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

What happens when a new version of the journey is activated and the audiences are still in the middle of old journey?

Comment: audience exists the old version of the journey, you will have to make the audience enter the new version of the journey.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Contacts in the old version continue to the end of the old Interaction. New Contacts entering into the Interaction are injected into the newly activated version.